# How to make an absolutely positioned div take all the available width space?

Tags: html, css

I have a wide image that I want to absolutely position a transparent div in its bottom.

```
 <div class="background">

 <img src="background.jpg" class="image">
 <div class="box">
 <p>paragraph</p>
 </div>

 </div>
```

css:

```
 .background {
 Position: relative;
 }

 .image {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 }

 .box {
 background: #CC333F;
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 }
```

problem is .box seems to be displayed as inline-block, I want it to take all the available width of the page, but it ends right where the paragraph does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also 
just add width:100%;
as in

```
.box {
 background: #CC333F;
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
width:100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

edit `.box` like this:

```
.box {
 background: #CC333F;
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right:0;   /* added  */
 left:0;   /* added  */
 }
```